# Поиск индекса класса через javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такая структура у сайта, и необходимо через javascript выполнить поиск по номеру класса `item_0000000`(где 0-индекс класса). Индекс у всех разный, возможно ли это осуществить?

```
<div class="featured-item col-sxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 center-block app_730_2 item_190888724"></div>
<div class="featured-item col-sxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 center-block app_730_2 item_190236263"></div>
<div class="featured-item col-sxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 center-block app_730_2 item_190564653"></div>
```

Нужно записать индекс у класса в переменную.

Comment: `$(".item_" + index)`

Comment: А как получить индекс со страницы, если их много?

Answer (score 0):

Хоть уже и не актуально, взялся изучать JS, беру некоторые вопросы, как задания для решения.

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('featured-item'); //все дивы
    for (let item of divs) {
      let className = item.className; //получаем содержимое класса каждого дива
      if (className.indexOf('item_') !== -1) {
        let startPosition = className.indexOf('item_'); //берём позицию, где начинается 'item_'
        let index = className.substr(startPosition+5,9); //достаём нужный индекс без 'item_'
        console.log(index);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Вы должны пояснить свое решение, а не объяснять, почему  вы выбрали этот вопрос.